# Array en nodeJS pierde sus elementos

Tags: javascript, nodejs, array

Buenas tardes, Tengo dos array: `usersConnected` y `users`.
Me encuentro trabajando con `NodeJS` y `Socketio` desarrollando un chat.

Para obtener los usuarios conectados les creo un UID en LocalStorage mismo que obtengo a través de socketio.

En NodeJS utilizo dos array llamados: `usersConnected` y `users`.

Cuando un usuario accede a la app verifico si su UID se encuentra en ambos arrays si no se encuentra lo guardo así:

```
 socket.on('users', function (user_uid) {

    if ( usersConnected.indexOf(user_uid) < 0 ) {
         usersConnected.push(user_uid);
    }

    if ( users.indexOf(user_uid) < 0 ) {
        users.push(user_uid);
    }

  });
```

Después si el usuario hace un refresh al sitio o lo abandona quito su UID del array usersConnected y espero 5 segundos.

Pasando 5 segundos si el usuario regresa se vuelve a registrar su UID en el array usersConnected pero si no regresa entonces verifico que ya no esté su UID en el array usersConnected  y lo elimino del array users para verificar quienes realmente están en el sitio. Esto lo hago así:

```
 socket.on('unload', function(user_uid){

     usersConnected.splice( usersConnected.indexOf(user_uid), 1);


        setTimeout(function () {
          if ( usersConnected.indexOf(user_uid) < 0 ) {

            var index = users.indexOf(user_uid);
            users.splice(index, 1);
          }
        }, 5000);

    });
```

Funciona bien cuando lo hago desde un solo navegador, si abro otro se registra bien su UID entonces tengo dos UID algo así: `[12345, 67890]` pero si actualizo mas de 3 veces desde cualquiera de los 2 navegadores no se que pasa que elimina a los demás UID's del array dejando solo su propio UID.

Hasta ahora no entiendo el motivo del porque al actualizar 3 veces se borran los demás UID, parece que sobrescribe el array users.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionando utilizando

> usersConnected.filter((user)=> user !== uid);

AL parecer si utilizaba:

> usersConnected.splice( usersConnected.indexOf(user_uid), 1);

Sobrescribia todo el array.

Saludos!